# Enter View from right to left like google drive

Tags: android, android-layout

Should I build a layout that works like google drive but I can not find information on the internet. How do I?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at [this](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)